# How to delete the timestamp from an UTC datetimestamp

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

I have created a script to scrape football data, a part of the data is the matchdate. I will add the scraped data into a json file.

The format of the date is like "May 13, 2018". I want to convert the data into the following format "2018-05-13".

The output of the script now is: "2018-05-13T22:00:00.000Z"

How can I delete the timestamp part from the script.

```
var lastDate =  'May 13, 2018';
    // console.log(lastDate);
// parse date into milliseconds     
var milliseconds = Date.parse(lastDate);
    // console.log(milliseconds);
// create new datetimestamp 
var newDate = new Date(milliseconds);
    // console.log(newDate);
// create datetimestamp UTC datetime    
newDate.setUTCDate(newDate.getDate());
    // console.log(newDate);    
var matchDate = newDate;

console.log(matchDate);
```

Comment: is this even legal to copy content from other pages?

Comment: I'm learning to use cheerio to scrape data from websites. This is to test the cheerio module and the scraped data will not be used.

Comment: programming 101. learn how variables work.

Answer (score 1):

By creating a variable outside the scope of the `.each` iteration, you can store the `day` value in the outer variable, in this case `firstDay`. Then, use `firstDay` when the condition of `day` is falsey.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

request('https://www.fotmob.com/leagues/47/matches/', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var firstDay;
    $('.fm-fixture').each(function(i, element){

      var a = $(this);
      var homeTeam = a.children().eq(1).children().text();
      var awayTeam = a.children().eq(3).children().text();
      var time = a.children().eq(2).children().text();
      var day = a.prev().text();
      // check if its the first iteration, if so then set firstDay
      if(i === 0) firstDay = day;
      // if the day is falsey then set day to firstDay
      day = day ? day : firstDay;
      var metadata = {
        homeTeam: homeTeam,
        awayTeam: awayTeam,
        time: time,
        day: day
      };
      console.log(metadata);
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. Go the following error message:      
i === 0 ? firstDay = day;
                                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: apologies, the breaking line should have been an `if` statement